# Windows Apache 2.4 - PHP cuRL not loading even though extension is set in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, curl, php-7

I am trying to activate curl on my Apache Server. So far it does not load.

I edited the php.ini file to allow the extension:

[image]

And I made sure using phpinfo() that I was editing the proper configuration file.

[image]

I restarted the server twice and made sure in php.ini that the extension folder (C:\php7\ext) was loaded correctly but curl still does not show on my phpinfo() page.

Why is this?

Comment: search for "apache LoadFile php curl"

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453219/windows-apache-2-4-php-curl-not-loading-even-though-extension-is-set-in-php-in